# Android: position of buttons in screens with different resolutions

Tags: android

My Android application consists of several UI screens that contain a background resource and buttons that are placed on top of it.
The position of the buttons on top of the background is determined in the xml file of the layout.
In screens with different resolutions the background is resized to fit the screen.
This creates a problem that the buttons are not placed in the right place on top the background.
For example:
Using an emulator I checked it on a variety of normal size screens.
The background I used is compatible to a 480x800 resolution with density 240.   But when I run it on an emulator with resolution of 640X960 and density of 320 the   background is resized and the buttons are not placed in the right place.
The same thing happens on an emulator with resolution of 320X480 and density of 160.

Comment: Please show the XML.  How are you positioning the buttons?  What kind of layout parent are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Consider not sizing the picture to the total size but setting it to a defined size. So you will have somehow a black frame around your picture but no problem with different screensizes.